# Variables with angle brackets in smarty

Tags: smarty

I want to print **<** sign in smarty using assign.

```
{assign var="scr" value="x"}
```

I tried:

```
{assign var="scr" value="{ldelim}"}
{assign var="scr" value="[<]"}
```

How to print angle bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Smarty 3.16

```
{assign var="scr" value="<"}
{$scr}
```

it works - it displays < sign. The same in Smarty 2.6.28 - it works without any problem